# Where is the error log for SharePoint Online failed add installs?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Uploaded an App to SharePoint Online App Catalog. Installed the App, and it failed as indicated by 'Installation Errors 1' on the 'Monitor' screen. Where can I find specific information about the error?

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint online, we cannot access the error log from client side. We can create service request to get the error log in SharePoint online.

For more information, refer to the article below.

How to create service requests to contact Office 365 support.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/

How to submit an Office 365 Dedicated/ITAR support incident online.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2694621/how-to-submit-an-office-365-dedicated-itar-support-incident-online

Answer (score 1):

If I am guessing the question correctly, then the Installation error for add-ins is always shown.

Just hover the mouse on **Install Error** count. And you will find the error in details.

For clarification refer to below image.

[image]